# Mechanical angle, electrical angle, and Park transformation

Tags: microcontroller, motor

I have a question about the electrical angle and mechanical angle of the BLDC motor.

The motor has 8 poles. We have

Electrical angle = number of pole pair * mechanical angle

This would mean that if the mechanical angle covers 45 deg, the electrical angle has spanned 360 deg. After that, should I reset my electrical angle to 0 and start counting again, or it's acceptable if the electrical angle keeps increasing?

I use the electrical angle in the Park transformation for calculations.

Comment: [Robert Park](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_H._Park) was a man- please capitalize his name in your title and text.

Comment: I am sorry. Can i edit now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is key is the electrical frame of reference. Every pole-pair the cycle completes.

For a 6 pole machine, 3pole-pair, this wrap (in the mechanical frame of reference) is every 120degrees

For an 8 pole machine, 4pole-pair, this wrap (in the mechanical frame of reference) is every 90degrees.

If you unwrap a machine stator (see below for a 2pole-pair) the difference becomes clear

[image]

Comment: No i am not able to understand.

Comment: What exactly don't you understand

Comment: If my mechanical angle is 360 then electrical angle will be 8 * 360 degrees, if it is 8 pole pair.  Please help.

Comment: The electrical angle would be 0 or 4*360 (as 0=360) if you were to unwrap the angle. I do not know you low level implementation but the usual method is to calculate mechanical, multiply by pole-pair count & ensure the register wraps

Comment: void encoderInterrupt(void)
{
  encoderincr++;
  mechanical_angle = encoderincr * 360 / ENCODER_COUNTER; /* ENCODER_COUNTER is the number of counts for one revolution */
  if(mechanical_angle > 360)
  {
    encoderincr=0;
  }
  electricalangle = NOPOLEPAIR * mechanical_angle;
}

Comment: i wanted to put in code blocks but unable to do it. Is the above logic is ok?